# Why does Drupal Schema.org module include RDFa instead of microdata?

Tags: drupal, microdata, schema.org, rdfa

Why does Google Structured Data Testing Tool show RDFa node data for Schema.org microdata? For example, see this [example](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://schema.openspring.net/person/dries-buytaert&view=) generated for the Drupal Schema.org module; this is an example of how to insert Schema.org microdata into your page, but the Drupal testing tool reports the microdata as `rdfa-node`. I thought Schema.org was a subset of microdata, which is different from RDFa? Has the testing tool just gotten confused?

Comment: Note that if you look at the source of the page that you're extracting data from, it begins with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`, and the markup of the page is using RDFa rather than a microdata format.

Comment: RDFa is *generally* more flexible than microdata.  It's essentially embedded RDF data, a well established standard.  So I would personally consider using RDFa, instead of microdata, a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained on the [schema.org module for Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) page, this module will output RDFa which is the syntax present in Drupal 7 core. RDFa is one schema.org syntax understood by Google parser, which is what it displays when you parse that page (rdfa-node). Microdata is another syntax for schema.org, if you prefer to use microdata with Drupal, you can use https://drupal.org/project/microdata